# Use __autoload to include class and use namespace

Tags: php, facebook

is there a possibility to do this?:

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    require_once("Facebook/". $classname .".php");
    use Facebook\$classname;
}
```

so that the namespace use works also?

Regards

Comment: __autoload just loads the classes I really use so why not then also let the autoload set the namespace (the way facebook sampled it)? I have to use the 'use' so or so - so why not do it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you can do this using the `class_alias` function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php).  It would probably look something like this:

```
function __autoload($classname) {
    require_once("Facebook/". $classname .".php");
    class_alias("Facebook\$classname", $classname, false); // last param is false so this doesn't create an infinite loop
}
```

However, even if you can do it, you shouldn't dynamically import namespaces and alias classes like that. It will make your code really confusing, and it essentially negates the function of namespaces (since every namespace you include will be aliased/imported). It's better to be explicit about your aliases and imports, in the files that actually use the class/namespace. It's much clearer.

`__autoload` is meant to hide the functionality of how you actually include the files containing your classes.  It's not necessary for the files that use a class to know how that class is included, just that it's accessible.  That's not true with aliasing/importing.  It's functionally important to know that a namespace is imported or that a class is aliased.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the advice. Btw: `use Facebook\$classname as $classname;` does not work

Comment: I know.  I don't think you can dynamically `use` like that anyway.  I'm just saying even if you could, you shouldn't   :)

Comment: @Michael I added a comment about the `class_alias` function that would allow you to do what you want to do.  But, just keep in mind the rest of the answer  :)